# SharePoint 2010 Migration to 2013

Tags: migration, claims, classic-mode-auth

I'm currently in the process of migrating from SharePoint 2010 which uses classic authentication to SharePoint 2013. The steps I have taken are:

- Created a new classic web application on SP2013
- Mounted the SP2010 DB via Powershell which converts the DB
- Converted the web application to use claims based authentication
- Migrated the users

The issue I am having is that a new user row is created in the UserInfo table. This is getting a new ID which is adding a new user profile in SP. When I create a document, it is created under the new user id, and not the old one. So when I click on the user name(same name) under the last modified user, the documents created in 2010 point at a different user to the ones created in 2013.

Is this normal behaviour? If not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to update existing 2010 web application to use Claims Authentication.. and than do the migration the same way? Of course try this in Test environment..

Comment: Did you follow: [Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx)

Comment: have you deleted the new web application content database before upgrade?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the pointers. Worked it out to be the AD in UAT was older than the one in live. So, when we took a backup from live to upgrade, some users where not in the UAT AD so were being created.

Answer (score 2):

I must say the to my knowledge the migration to Claims should be done PRIOR to moving to SharePoint 2013, therefore in SharePoint 2010. In your case I'm wondering if the creation of the new user in User Information List isn't happening also because SID are not correctly copied.

Also to check the differences - could take one "new" user and one "old" user and see if for the OLD user the actual name is really Claims or classical account name (if NOT claims - it means that the actual "user migration" has not happened to claims)?

Comment: +1 on converting to claims in 2010